# Json Response Query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am now working on getting a Json response from the data in the following table

[image]

**By using the following Query :**

```
$sql = "select * from subject where subject_name = 'maths'";

$result =  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $data = new stdClass();
    $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
    $unit = $row['unit'];
    $unit_name = $row['unit_name'];

    $data->subject_name=$subject_name;

    $emparray[] = array('unit' => $unit,
                        'unit_name' => $unit_name,
                        );

     $data->units=$emparray;
    }

echo json_encode(array($data));
```

**I can get the Json response as :**

[image]

Now what i want was for overall subjects without using where clause (where subject_name = 'maths')

**My required Json o/p is as below :**

[image]

Comment: You probably need to do multiple queries (first find how many subjects there are, then loop each subject) or do logic with PHP (group items with same subject name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group result by **subject_name** to your **PHP array** by following code.

```
$sql    = "select * from users";
```

**OR**

```
$sql    = "select subject_name,unit,unit_name from users";
```

**PHP CODE**

```
$result =  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$data   = array();

function search($subject){
  global $data;
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value['subject_name']) && $value['subject_name']==$subject) {
        return $key;
      }
  }
 return false;
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $res = search($row['subject_name']);
  if ($res===false) {
    array_push($data, array(
            'subject_name' =>$row['subject_name'],
            'units'=>array($row)
        )
    );
  }else{
    array_push($data[$res]['units'], $row);
  }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Now you can get your **JSON** format from above code.

Comment: Hello , your code gives array like "English " but i need with key like "subject_name  : English". Kindly check the required json o/p in my question mate . can you clarify me how to get that done

Comment: Ahh! Yes Sure! wait please. I am updating code for you! @RajaGopal

Comment: There was a little bit mistake. I updated again. Now fixed. Check please. @RajaGopal

Comment: Thanks a lot sumon , Thanks for your hard work on this question , marked this answer as working :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125151/discussion-between-sumon-sarker-and-raja-gopal).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code

```
  $sql = "select * from subject;

    $result =  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        while($query_row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

    if($query_row['subject_name'] == 'English'){
                        $timeslot = array(
                            "unit"      => $query_row['unit'],
                            "unit_name" => $query_row['unit_name']
                        );

                        $subjects   = addToArray($subjects, $timeslot['subject_name']);

                    } else if($query_row['subject_name'] == 'Maths'){
                        $timeslot = array(
                        "unit"      => $query_row['unit'],
                            "unit_name" => $query_row['unit_name']
                        );

                        $subjects   = addToArray($subjects, $timeslot['subject_name']);


                    } else if($query_row['subject_name'] == 'Science'){
                        $timeslot = array(
                            "unit"      => $query_row['unit'],
                            "unit_name" => $query_row['unit_name']
                        );
        $subjects   = addToArray($subjects, $timeslot['subject_name']);
                    }

    }
```

Comment: Hello , what i want was not by subject name in the code. subject name might change in the future so i want to take by subject name in the db not directly in the code

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$sql = " select subject_name, group_concat(unit) unit, group_concat(unit_name) unit_name
          from subject group by subject_name ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
    $units = explode( ',', $row['unit'] );
    $unit_names = explode( ',', $row['unit_name'] );

    $subject = [];
    $subject['subject_name'] = $subject_name;

    $emparray = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($units); $i++) {
        $emparray[] = array('unit' => $units[$i], 'unit_name' => $unit_names[$i]);
    }

    $subject['units'] = $emparray;
    $data[] = $subject;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

My code may not be exactly correct, but may still help you

```
$outer_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT subject_name * from subject;
  $outer_result =  mysqli_query($conn,$outer_sql);
  while($outer_query_row= mysqli_fetch_array($outer_result))
  {
 $sql = "select * from subject where subject_name = '".$outer_query_row['subject_name']."'";

 $result =  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$data = new stdClass();
$subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
$unit = $row['unit'];
$unit_name = $row['unit_name'];

$data->subject_name=$subject_name;

$emparray[] = array('unit' => $unit,
                    'unit_name' => $unit_name,
                    );

 $data->units=$emparray;
}


  }
echo json_encode(array($data));
```